# How to know image encoding using PHP

Tags: php, image

I would like to know whether there is a way to know which way an image is encoded. My case is like this,

I have 2 '.jpg' files, says 'a.jpg' and 'b.jpg'. I can open those two images. But the problem is, b.jpg is actually 'b.png' that i just renamed it to 'b.jpg'.

Question is, how to know that 'b.jpg' is actually a PNG Image file using PHP ?

Thanks..

Comment: ops, i'm sorry... i didn't search well before so i didn't found it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)... e.g.

`exif_imagetype('a.jpg')` should return 2

and

`exif_imagetype('b.jpg')` should return 3

Refer to the following list to see what value refers to which encoding:

**Value Constant**

```
1   IMAGETYPE_GIF 
2   IMAGETYPE_JPEG 
3   IMAGETYPE_PNG 
4   IMAGETYPE_SWF 
5   IMAGETYPE_PSD 
6   IMAGETYPE_BMP 
7   IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (intel byte order) 
8   IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (motorola byte order) 
9   IMAGETYPE_JPC 
10  IMAGETYPE_JP2 
11  IMAGETYPE_JPX 
12  IMAGETYPE_JB2 
13  IMAGETYPE_SWC 
14  IMAGETYPE_IFF 
15  IMAGETYPE_WBMP 
16  IMAGETYPE_XBM 
17  IMAGETYPE_ICO
```

Comment: I stuck around for days just because the 'b.jpg' do not show up when i try to generate a PDF output using TCPDF image tag ( <img src='b.jpg'> ).but now it has been solved. Thanks, George ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the mime type of the file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, 'b.jpg'); // image/png
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: Hmm.. why i get 'Fatal Error: call to undefined function' when i try it? I use XAMPP 1.8.1 for windows.

Comment: May you don't have installed or enable the FileInfo extension. http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

This should be what you're looking for.

Example giving on PHP.net:

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
?>
```